# Compound Rate as a Function of Market Interest Rate

Tags: calculation, interest-rate, compound-interest

I have these two pictures from Investopedia. [Here is the link to the page](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/07/continuously_compound.asp).

[image]

[image]

I am confused by this concept. How is the quarterly compound rate 11.825% with a 12% annual rate? Furthermore, how is the DAILY rate 11.66% when the annual rate is 12%.

This just doesn't make sense to me. Could someone explain this, and with that explanation tell me how I can get back from any of these rates (11.825%, 11.71%, 11.66%) back to 12%.

It seems that in the last two examples they are using 6 months (1/6) and 180 days (1/180) instead of 12 (1/12) months and 360(1/360) days in their exponent calculation. Is this an error or am I misunderstanding/misreading this information?

Answer (score 3):

Generally this is referred to as the Annual Percentage Rate (APR), and the Annual Percentage Yield (APY).  At the same percentage rate different compounding methods will generate different yields; with daily compounding being most preferable to the saver.

The basic concept is that interest accrues on the principle.  Frequency at which the interest is counted toward your principle impacts your annual yield.

Daily

```
Day Principle   Interest
1   10000.00    3.33
2   10003.33    3.33
3   10006.67    3.34
4   10010.00    3.34
5   10013.34    3.34
6   10016.68    3.34
7   10020.02    3.34
8   10023.36    3.34
9   10026.70    3.34
10  10030.04    3.34
11  10033.38    3.34
13  10036.73    3.35
etc.
```

As you can see from here the interest is credited to you every day, as a result of this compounding effect your interest payments grow each every few days.

Monthly:

```
Mon.Day.Principle   Interest
1   1   10000.00    3.33
1   2   10000.00    3.33
1   3   10000.00    3.33
~~~~
1   27  10000.00    3.33
1   28  10000.00    3.33
1   29  10000.00    3.33
1   30  10000.00    3.33

2   1   10096.67    3.37
2   2   10096.67    3.37
2   3   10096.67    3.37
2   4   10096.67    3.37
```

As you can see here, the interest accrues on the principle every day, but its only credited at the end of the month.  As a result your interest payments only increase at the beginning of the next month.  This effect is again exacerbated in quarterly, semi-annual and annual compounding.

Comment: Quid is correct. This is why Einstein said that compounding is the most powerful thing in the universe. In essence you get Intrest on the interest. So a yearly Intrest rate will always be higher than the multiple of the monthly rate if paid monthly. To double your money in seven years only requires an interest rate of 10.0409, even though 7 times 10 is only 70,not 100.

Comment: 0.95%, paid monthly, yealds just a hair more than 12%, even though 0.95 × 12 = 11.4.

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't answer my question. How is an 11.66% *DAILY* compound rate equivalent and/or a function of a 12% *ANNUAL* rate?

Comment: Why are these numbers (1/6) for monthly and (1/180) for daily, and not (1/12), (1/360) respectively?

Comment: Ahh. I think I understand now. The wording on investopedia was not clear.